# Passing multiple line value from JCL instream to Cobol variable 88

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

Example:

```
01  VAR1             PIC 9(05).      
    88 WS-VAR1  VALUE 1000 1001 1002 1003      
       1004 1009 2000 2002 3000 4000 4009           
       5000 5001 6000 7000 8000 2332 8484.
```

How can we pass value from JCL as instream to a Cobol program variable 88.
So, that it will be easier to modify the value without changing the program.

Two solutions which I found:
1. Using internal indexed table. So that Binary search will do the task fast.
2. Using VSAM file instead of passing data instream. (Less likely)

I think Binary search definitely be slower than 88 condition check.
I am trying to find something of equivalent efficiency as of 88 condition check.

Comment: You cant. What you would do is have `table`, load the table from JCL and search the Table

Comment: Thanks Bruce for you quick answer. Is there any other way to do this? I will choose the better approach among them.

Comment: Are you looking to take a value from JCL like a PARM='nnnn' ?  I think the 88 is  a red herring.

Comment: @Hogstrom Any solution which is simple and works, is fine.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to pass a value from JCL PARM= or from SYSIN to make the COBOL program independent of a hard coded value.

This web [article](http://www.simotime.com/cblpar01.htm) has a good explanation of how you can accomplish this.

JCL looks like this:

```
//* ******************************************************************* 
//* Step 2 of 4, Execute the COBOL program with a parameter. //*
//PARJ1S02 EXEC PGM=CBLPARC1, 
//             PARM='This is a Parameter from the EXEC and PARM= ...'
```

and in the COBOL program linkage section:

```
  *****************************************************************
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01  PARM-BUFFER.
       05  PARM-LENGTH         pic S9(4)   comp.
       05  PARM-DATA           pic X(256).
```

In your case you can validate the data passed in the linkage section based on your criteria.  So, once validated, you could move the value from the linkage section after converting it to a numeric value for the test.

Comment: I believe `PARM` is limited to 100 bytes. To pass more than 100 bytes `PARMDD` must be used and the executed program must then call `CEE3PR2` to retrieve the value.

Comment: I don't believe CEE3PR2 is necessary unless you are in an LE environment (which COBOL is, of course), you used CEE3PRM, and you now might be dealing with passed PARMDD values over 100 bytes. TSO CALL command processing also has a silly 100 byte limit, and you have to play games (invoking from REXX using ADDRESS LINKMVS works well). For non-LE code, the area pointed to by R1 is the same, just longer.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr my statement about the 100 byte limit is based on [the documentation for PARM.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieab600/iea3b6_Syntax89.htm)

Comment: My concern is with mentioning CEE3PR2. A main program with a LINKAGE SECTION consisting of an 01 entry with a 05 9(5) BINARY and an 05 X(32000) should be enough.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr I'll take your word for it -- I'm not in a position to test it.

Comment: If our zPDT would stabilize…